# Impossible to start application after upgrade to spring boot 3 and jakarta Faces 4

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, primefaces, mojarra, jakarta-migration

I' trying to migrate a spring boot application from spring boot 2.7.8 to 3.0.6. The application uses jsf mojarra and primefaces for GUI. The application works fine with spring boot 2.7.8
Spring boot 3 uses spring 6, which needs java 17, and tomcat 10. So I must migrate java EE to jakarta EE 10 and jakarta Faces 4.
Unfortunately, the application server doesn't start after migration.
`Error : Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI? Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getExternalContext()" because "context" is null`

full stack trace :

```
[2023-05-12 13:53:48,821] ERROR jakarta.faces copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext - Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
[2023-05-12 13:53:48,824] ERROR jakarta.faces logNoFactory - L’application n’a pas été initialisée correctement au démarrage. Impossible de localiser la Fabrique : jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
[2023-05-12 13:53:48,824] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/etcsst] log - Servlet.init() for servlet [FacesServlet] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.notNullFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:496) ~[jakarta.jakartaee-api-10.0.0.jar:?]
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:190) ~[jakarta.jakartaee-api-10.0.0.jar:?]
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:263) ~[jakarta.jakartaee-api-10.0.0.jar:?]
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.acquireFacesContextFactory(FacesServlet.java:493) ~[jakarta.jakartaee-api-10.0.0.jar:?]
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:342) ~[jakarta.jakartaee-api-10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:808) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:84) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:3215) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:67) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:305) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:216) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) [?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) [spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) [spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) [spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587) [spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) [spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) [spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) [spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) [spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at ch.sbb.Application.main(Application.java:24) [classes/:?]
```

pom-file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
</project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>etcsst-cloud</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.20.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Additional JSF libs: Sun's JSF API and Impl. (Mojarra), PrimeFaces and Jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <!-- scope provided should be enough ? -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <!--
                probleme : server starts with 3.0.4, but 3.0.4 is not compatible with jakarta.jakartaee-web-api 10, which is needed for tomcat 10
                with version 4.0.1, the server doesn't start, the context not loaded,
                Error : Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
            -->
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <!-- <version>3.0.4</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- file upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mailing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TODO remove after successful migration -->
        <!--spring property management für spring boot upgrade-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Jsf Servlet configuration :

```
import jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener;
import com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import ch.sbb.rsw.estamigration.spring.RestoreSpringSessionListener;

@Configuration
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JsfServletConfigurator implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Value("${javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE}") // = Development, Production
    private String jsfProjectStage;

    @Value("${server.servlet.context-path}") // /etcsst
    private String dispatcherServletPath; // /etcsst, wird seit spring boot 2.0.9 nötig

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        log.debug("servlet configurator. jsf project stage : '" + jsfProjectStage + "'");

        // kommentare aus xhtml-seiten kommen nicht in output
        servletContext.setInitParameter("jakarta.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "nova-light");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("jakarta.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", jsfProjectStage);
// sandbox zone, nothing helps
//        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager_INJECTION_PROVIDER_TASK", "com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider");
//        servletContext.setAttribute("com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager_INJECTION_PROVIDER_TASK", "com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider");
//        servletContext.setAttribute("com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager_INJECTION_PROVIDER_TASK", new WebContainerInjectionProvider());
//        servletContext.setInitParameter("jakarta.faces.CONFIG_FILES", "/META-INF/faces-config.xml");
//        servletContext.setAttribute("jakarta.faces.CONFIG_FILES", "/META-INF/faces-config.xml");
//        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.injectionProvider", "com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider");
        // source : stackoverflow.com/questions/73112899/spring-boot-3-and-jsf-with-jakarta-not-working
//        servletContext.setAttribute(com.sun.faces.RIConstants.FACES_INITIALIZER_MAPPINGS_ADDED, Boolean.TRUE); // constant fehlt in 4.0.1, comes from 3.0.0
//        servletContext.setAttribute("com.sun.faces.facesInitializerMappingsAdded", Boolean.TRUE);

        // because of Annotation ReinitAfterPassivation. 
        servletContext.addListener(RestoreSpringSessionListener.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> jsfServletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet facesServlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet>(facesServlet, "*.xhtml", "/logout",
                // urls for oauth2/SSO
                "/oauth2/authorization/*", "/login/oauth2/code/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("FacesServlet");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    // returns /etcsst, needed from spring boot 2.0.9
    public DispatcherServletPath jsfServletPathBean() {
        return () -> dispatcherServletPath;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
}
```

faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
        xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
        xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
        https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_4_0.xsd"
        version="4.0">
 
    <application>
        <!-- 
            RswSpringBeanFacesELResolver is an extension of SpringBeanFacesELResolver. Checks user roles, reads mask labels from database
        -->
        <el-resolver>
            ch.sbb.rsw.etcsst.web.util.RswSpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
     
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>de</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>it</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <message-bundle>EtcsstResources</message-bundle>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>EtcsstResources</base-name>
            <var>Msgs</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>ch.sbb.rsw.estamigration.jsf.MultipleFormSubmitPreventionPhaseListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>

    <factory>
        <!-- Doesn't help. The RswExceptionHandlerFactory was already defined here and worked before upgrade. 
        After upgrade, a display in constructor doesn't longer appear in log, so the class is no longer loaded after upgrade 
        defining FacesContextFactoryImpl here has no effect
        -->
        <faces-context-factory>com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl</faces-context-factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>
            ch.sbb.rsw.estamigration.exception.RswExceptionHandlerFactory
        </exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>

    <!-- NAVIGATION RULES -->
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <converter>
        <converter-for-class>ch.sbb.rsw.etcsst.model.Aktor</converter-for-class>
        <converter-class>ch.sbb.rsw.etcsst.web.converter.AktorConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
    ... here more converters
        
</faces-config>
```

If I use instead of org.glassfish:jakarta.faces:4.0.1 the version 3.0.4, the server starts fine, but as 3.0.4 is not compatible with jakarta EE 10, it fails on the first attempt to display a xhtml-page, 3.0.4 trying to call classes/methods of jakarta EE 9 missing in jakarta EE 10
Debugging FactoryFinderInstance, the faces context is missing (but exists with 3.0.4)

I tried to define the Factory classes as services in META-INF/services,
example, file named jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory with content `org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContextFactory`
the defined class will be loaded, but the error `Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?` appear for each so injected class, the server still doesn't start

I tried to define the Factory classes in faces-config.xml too, see whole file below, it hasn's any effect

```
    <factory>
        <!-- Doesn't help. The RswExceptionHandlerFactory was already defined here and worked before upgrade. 
        After upgrade, a display in constructor doesn't longer appear in log, so the class is no longer loaded after upgrade 
        defining FacesContextFactoryImpl here has no effect
        -->

        <faces-context-factory>com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl</faces-context-factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>
            ch.sbb.rsw.estamigration.exception.RswExceptionHandlerFactory
        </exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
```

I tried to define a configuration class for Faces config :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import jakarta.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

// this class should be able to replace the file faces-config.xml, which won't be loaded/understood/processed with jakarta-faces 4
// source hantsy.gitbook.io/java-ee-8-by-example/jsf/jsf-activation
// without @Configuration annotation, the class won't be instanciated
@Configuration
@FacesConfig
@Slf4j
public class Grmbl {
    public Grmbl(){
        log.error("!!! INSTANTIATION DE @FacesConfig par Grmbll");
    }
}
```

I looked for a solution on the net, tried about all possible hints, nothing helps, I'm stuck on the same error message

Any help, any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still trying without success.
Does somebody know a working "hello world" example of an application using spring boot 3 and jakarta-faces 4 ? It could help greatly

Comment: I would also like to know if there is an example of Spring Boot 3, JSF and Jakarta-Faces 4. Still not found one.

Comment: But there is a JoinFaces example you can try out with Spring Boot 3.1.1 https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-maven-jar-example

Answer (score 0):

I replaced mojarra by myFaces.
I could solve the problem using a hello world-example basing on this post :
https://prog.world/jakarta-faces-and-spring-boot/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).